# Suction hose in my watering system getting air. What can be the problem?

Tags: water-pressure, pump

I have a water deposit, with a pressure booster pump, very similar to this one:

[image: pump]

Recently the pump stopped working properly. I don't get any water in the tap and, after inspection, I see that the suction hose has air.

I've solved the issue by filling the hose with water, but the problem happens again.

What might the problem be? What are the most common cases to get air into the suction hose?
What can I do to prevent the pump from eventually working dry (it didn't get to that point)?

Comment: small hole or leaking joint - once found then re-seal.

Answer (score 2):

Leak at a fitting.

Leak from cracks in the body of the hose - common for aged plastic hose exposed to sunlight, for instance. Or hose which has been chewed by animals.

Sucking water fast enough to either create a vortex (whirlpool) in the supply that brings air to the hose-end below the surface, or simply sucking the level of the supply down below the hose-end.

Comment: Since it contains air, is it to be expected that the leak is over the water or can it also be in the under water part of the hose?

Comment: @nsn if the water drags down for the leak to be exposed to air that leak will suck in air.